# Indent multiple lines in Emacs

Tags: emacs, edit

I am looking for shortcuts or functions to add one tab to all lines in the selection. Also how to reduce one tab to all lines in the selection?

There are multiple references for this. But I could not find one that mimics use of tab and shift-tab on selected text as in regular editors like geany. There one can select multiple lines and then use tab or shift-tab to move text left and right till one finds it best.

I found `C-x tab <left> or <right>`  : this moves all lines in the selection to left or right one space at a time. `C-5 C-x tab` move it 5 spaces but then stops. But I want these lines to move tab spaces at a time while keeping the selection so that I can repeat or undo the process. How can I do that?

Basically, I need a function which I can call after selecting some lines. It should:

- Detect the selected lines
- On pressing a key (say 1 on num pad) it should move selected text to left by 5 spaces (and keeping the selection)
- On pressing another key (say 3 on num pad), it should move selected text to right by 5 spaces (and keep selection)
- The function should end on pressing ENTER.

Can above ability be added to `C-x tab` shortcut, which works exactly like that (with left and right keys) but it moves selected text only one space at a time.

Comment: But that is for python files (files with extension py). I want to do this in text files (extension .txt) also. In addition, these commands work only once. To repeat one has to do `C-c >` again and not just `>`

Comment: What are the shortcut-key combinations for `python-indent-shift-right` and `python-indent-shift-left` (they works in both py and txt files)? `Control-c >` and `Control-c <`works only in py files but not in  in txt files.

Comment: Hitting `C-x TAB` followed by `S-<right>` and `S-<left>` could do it.  If you're having trouble with using that, then say so.  You may be using a mode that might not have tab-stops.  See `C-h v indent-rigidly-map RET`.

Answer (score 6):

> I am looking for shortcuts or functions to add one tab to all lines in the selection.

First select a region.

```
C-SPC [set-mark-command]
```

Select region of lines, with the mark at beginning of first line and the point at the beginning of last last line (or vice versa), and then

```
C-x r t [string-rectangle]
C-q TAB [quoted-insert]
```

> I found `C-x TAB` `<left>` or `<right>`: this moves all lines in the selection to left or right one space at a time.

Did you see on option for hitting `S-<left>` and `S-<right>`?  That should do it for you,  `Shift + Right`, perhaps only depending on what mode you are in and whether `indent-tabs-mode` is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you use evil-mode, you have the key `>` that indents the current line or the selection to one level, according to the mode. I don't know how to make it insert tabs. By a quick look at the documentation by keywords (`C-h d indent tab RET`) it looks like we have the variable `indent-tabs-mode`:

> indentation can insert tabs if this is non nil

More generally, this doesn't seem to suit your requirements but nearly in that it helps on indenting multiple lines in a row and repeatedly: [indent-tools](https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/indent-tools) (on melpa) (my toy). It's meant for indentation-based files (so yaml, python,…) and it gives an hydra (which helps to repeat the actions) with the commands: indent or de-indent the current block of indentation, the paragraph, etc, and the same to comment, delete, fold, and move around blocks of indentation.